# Mantener seleccionado un icono con .net

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net

Estoy trabajando con un formulario de .net c#, lo que estoy realizando es mostrar un `<ul>` de iconos fontawebsome y el usuario selecciona uno y cambia el color para identificar cual seleccionò, en otros campos del formulario agrego RequiredFieldValidator para validar que no estén vacíos los campos, el problema que tengo es que si hay campos vacios se activan los validadores y la seleccion del icono ya no se muestra por lo que debo seleccionar nuevamente el icono es lo que deseo evitar, Que puedo hacer? Como puedo hacerlo con JQuery o JS este es mi codigo JS que selecciona el icono

```
        var iconos = document.querySelectorAll('.fa');
        var input = document.getElementById('<%=txtIcono.ClientID%>');

        for (var i = 0; i < iconos.length; i++) {
            iconos[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
                input.value = this.className;
                var div1 = document.getElementById('capa');

            });
        }
```

Este es mi formulario

```html
<table border="0" width="75%">
                        <tr>
                            <td>Icono del Anuncio:
                            </td>
                            <td align="left">
                                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtIcono" MaxLength="100" SkinID="txtGral" Width="582px" onkeydown="javascript:return false" Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="rfIcono" ControlToValidate="txtIcono" ErrorMessage="*Seleccione un icono para el anuncio." Display="Dynamic" EnableClientScript="true">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td align="left">

                                <div id="capa" style="display: block;">
                                    <ul id="navegador" class="social-icons icon-circle list-unstyled list-inline">
                                        <li class="enlace"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-android"></i></a></li>
                                        <li class="enlace"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-apple"></i></a></li>
                                        <li class="enlace"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bitcoin"></i></a></li>
                                        <li class="enlace"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-css3"></i></a></li>
                                        <li class="enlace"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dropbox"></i></a></li>
                                        <li class="enlace"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                                        <li class="enlace"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square"></i></a></li>
                                        <li class="enlace"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a></li>
                                        <li class="enlace"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-html5"></i></a></li>
                                        <li class="enlace"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
                                        <li class="enlace"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
                                        <li class="enlace"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin-square"></i></a></li>
                                        <li class="enlace"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linux"></i></a></li>
                                        <li class="enlace"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pinterest"></i></a></li>
                                        <li class="enlace"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pinterest-square"></i></a></li>
                                        <li class="enlace"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-skype"></i></a></li>
                                        <li class="enlace"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-trello"></i></a></li>
                                        <li class="enlace"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-tumblr"></i></a></li>
                                        <li class="enlace"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-tumblr-square"></i></a></li>
                                        <li class="enlace"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                                        <li class="enlace"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square"></i></a></li>
                                        <li class="enlace"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-vimeo-square"></i></a></li>
                                        <li class="enlace"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-windows"></i></a></li>
                                        <li class="enlace"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a></li>
                                        <li class="enlace"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-youtube-play"></i></a></li>
                                        <li class="enlace"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-youtube-square"></i></a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td align="right" style="width: 126px">Titulo del Anuncio:
                            </td>
                            <td align="left">
                                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtTitulo" MaxLength="199" SkinID="txtGral" Width="582px"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" ControlToValidate="txtTitulo" ErrorMessage="*Ingrese un titulo para el anuncio." EnableClientScript="true">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="top" align="right" style="width: 126px;">
                                <div style="padding-top: 12px">Cuerpo del Anuncio:</div>
                            </td>
                            <td align="left">
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" ControlToValidate="txtCuerpo" ErrorMessage="*Ingrese el cuerpo del anuncio." EnableClientScript="true">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                <CKEditor:CKEditorControl ID="txtCuerpo" BasePath="../AnunciosPortal/JS/" runat="server" Height="490px" Width="595px"></CKEditor:CKEditorControl>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right" style="width: 126px">Archivo:
                            </td>
                            <td align="left">
                                <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
                                <hr />
                                <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" ForeColor="Red" runat="server" />
                                <asp:Label ID="lblMessage1" ForeColor="Green" runat="server" />
                                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtArchivo" SkinID="txtGral" Width="168px" Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                        </tr>


                        <tr>
                            <td align="right" style="width: 126px">Pagina principal:
                            </td>
                            <td align="left">
                                <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkStatus" Checked="true" Text="" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right" style="width: 126px">Color:
                            </td>
                            <td>

                                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtColor" class="demo" data-control="brightness" data-position="bottom right" value="#32CD32" onkeydown="javascript:return false" MaxLength="20" SkinID="txtGral" Width="143px"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" ControlToValidate="txtColor" ErrorMessage="*Seleccione color." EnableClientScript="true">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right" style="width: 126px">Inicio de vigencia:
                            </td>
                            <td align="left">
                                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtFechai" MaxLength="20" SkinID="txtGral" Width="168px"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" ControlToValidate="txtFechai" ErrorMessage="*Seleccione la fecha inicial del anuncio." EnableClientScript="true">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right" style="width: 126px">Fin de vigencia:
                            </td>
                            <td align="left">
                                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtFechaf" MaxLength="20" SkinID="txtGral" Width="168px"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" ControlToValidate="txtFechaf" ErrorMessage="*Seleccione la fecha final del anuncio." EnableClientScript="true">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
```

Comment: Estas utilizando Asp [tag:webforms]?

Comment: @Einer asi es, pero surgio la necesidad antes descrita y es por ello que estoy usando JS y .net